# how can I remove orders and returns at the footer links

Tags: magento, sticky-footer

how can I remove “orders and returns” at the footer link? I am new to Magento, anyone who can explain the steps in a detailed way? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Guest/Links.php

comment out

```
public function __construct()
{
    if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        /*$this->_label       = $this->__('Orders and Returns');
        $this->_title       = $this->__('Orders and Returns');
        $this->_url         = $this->getUrl('sales/guest/form');  */

        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

to do it properly you should copy the file into app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Block/Guest/Links.php
before edit.

Comment: This will not remove the link HTML it self, just the link attributes such as href and anchor text.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make changes in sales.xml file

Answer (score 0):

The answer, like typical in Magento, is in xml.
The best way to remove that area entirely is using local.xml
So, for example, in your app/design/PACKAGE-NAME/THEME-NAME/layout/local.xml
You would want to have this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layout>
  <default>
    <reference name="footer">
      <!-- footer_links is the main footer links -->
      <remove name="footer_links"></remove>
      <!-- footer_links2 is the one labeled Account, with My Account and Orders and returns under it -->
      <remove name="footer_links2"></remove>
    </reference>
  </default>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who arrived here and didn't find the solution: I've found it in [this link](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-remove-orders-and-returns-link.html#gref).

Like @Muk has pointed out the file you have to modify is `\app\design\frontend\PACKAGE_NAME\THEME_NAME\layout\sales.xml`. If your theme doesn't have it you'll have to copy the original one from `\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout` and alter the copied version.

Comment out this part:

```
<reference name="footer_links">
    <block type="sales/guest_links" name="return_link"/>
    <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>return_link</blockName></action>
</reference>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

I haven't got access to a vanilla copy of magento but from memory footer_links can be edited via the admin panel.

CMS -> Static Blocks -> Footer Links

You can then edit the links via the editor. If it is not located there it will be pulled in via the footer.phtml file which I can go through if this fails.